# Upload a Cover (PHP)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-opengraph, cover

Anybody know how to upload a profile cover? Not a Album cover but a profile cover for the new timeline? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Facebook will roll out a specific API for that in the future, but so far the only way is to upload the photo via the photo API and then ask the user to choose it as his cover...

To upload a photo use a HTTP POST to https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos (as seen on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for this just yet.

Comment: I don't know how it's doing that, but it's not using a cover_picture API.