# How do I use the graph api to change the cover image of an album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Given an Album ID, how do I tell FB through the graph api to change the cover image of an album?

Comment: I would love to know this myself. There is no information about this that I can find. Your question might be short, but here is an example of a logical approach that just doesnt work: http://d.pr/i/5ai4

Answer (score 0):

It seems the API doesn't provide this feature. Refer to : [Upload a Cover (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563343/upload-a-cover-php)

Good luck
A.